# Is the default lodash memoize function a danger for memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to use `memoize` but I have a concern that the cache will grow indefinitely until sad times occur.

I couldn't find anything via google/stackoverflow searches.

P.S. I am using lodash v4.

Comment: It would not be: it works exactly as intended. If you want to "flush" the cache - just re-create a wrapped function. It's barely a leak since you deliberately and voluntarily store all the data.

Comment: You can also use WeakMap as your cache if it's available to you, and you are keying by object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lodash retains all the memoized data unless you specify a different Cache type.

---

The default cache is lodash's MapCache:
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.14.0/lodash.js#L1968

The memoized values are stored in different data structures depending on whether the key is suitable for hashing (and whether or not ES6 Map is available in the environment):

- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.14.0/lodash.js#L1987
- https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.14.0/lodash.js#L5561

If you look at the `set` methods of all of these data structures, you'll notice there is no provision for anything like LRU etc:

- `Hash#set`: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.14.0/lodash.js#L1832
- `ListCache#set`: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.14.0/lodash.js#L1940
- `Map#set`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set

Comment: LRU would break the whole concept of memoization and break its contract.

Comment: I've used memoizee with LRU ("max" option) in the past as a handy way to cache expensive rendering output. In that particular application I was getting batches of matching inputs to my function, but over time the inputs would change. Cache misses were less important than not chewing up memory.

Comment: I've accepted this, although I may have missed the memory leak term, this answer does get at the heart of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer is no.

When you use a `memoize` function you accept a contract that:

1. The function will only be invoked once with a given argument
2. The cache stays there as long as it's necessary to guarantee the #1 (forever)

So only the implementation that keeps data forever can comply with the requirements.

What is very often confused - is a "memory leak" thing with just "inefficient" use of memory.

In this case - if it is a problem for you, then it is your responsibility to re-create a memoized function when it's good for your algorithm. Since it is only you that knows when it is safe to do so, and it cannot be done automatically.

Comment: Good answer too, I think I just misused the term memory leak. My concern is in fact the overconsumption of memory. Guess there is a slight difference of meaning to be aware of here. Thanks

Comment: So in the end I used a library called `reselect` which would respond to changes in my application state (I am using react/redux) and would then output a memoized function.  I think this is in line with what you are suggesting.  I also had to provide my own memoize resolver as I am using multiple arguments to the function.  Unit tests are working.  Thanks!